# Simplest method to check whether unordered_map of unordered_maps contains key

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I am using an unordered_map of unordered_maps, such that I can reference an element using the "multi key" syntax:

`my_map[k1][k2]`.

Is there a convenient way to use the same "multi-key" syntax to check whether an element exists before trying to access it? If not, what is the simplest way?

Comment: C++ 20 finally has this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains. Why does it takes so long to bring in such an everybody-that-is-not-crazy-think-obviously-should-have feature?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If your intention is to test for the existence of the key, I would not use

```
my_map[k1][k2]
```

because [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) will default construct a new value for that key if it does not already exist.

Rather I would prefer to use [`std::unordered_map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find). So if you are certain the first key exists, but not the second you could do

```
if (my_map[k1].find(k2) != my_map[k1].end())
{
    // k2 exists in unordered_map for key k1
}
```

If you would like to make a function that checks for the existence of **both** keys, then you could write something like

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// \brief Determines a nested map contains two keys (the outer containing the inner)
/// \param[in] data Outer-most map
/// \param[in] a    Key used to find the inner map
/// \param[in] b    Key used to find the value within the inner map
/// \return True if both keys exist, false otherwise
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class key_t, class value_t>
bool nested_key_exists(std::unordered_map<key_t, std::unordered_map<key_t, value_t>> const& data, key_t const a, key_t const b)
{
    auto itInner = data.find(a);
    if (itInner != data.end())
    {
        return itInner->second.find(b) != itInner->second.end();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And if you aren't certain that `k1` exists, you'll want to use `find` twice - once to check for `k1` and once to check for `k2`.

Comment: @zmb I think that is what I need.

Comment: @user997112 In that case you can use the `nested_key_exists` function in the lower portion of the answer. It will return `true` if both keys exist, `false` otherwise.

Comment: @CoryKramer thank you, this is a very good, easy-to-understand answer. I will test it and then accept.

Comment: It is not clear if value `my_map[k1]` would be cached so two lookups could be expensive

Comment: @Slava Good point, if that is a concern the inner map retrieved from `my_map[k1]` could be stored in a temporary variable to avoid doing the lookup twice.

Comment: Note that this only works for `unordered_map` - even though the logic is exactly the same for `map`.  Yakk's answer would work for both, and would even extend to a 'map of maps of maps'

Comment: Coming in C++20: std::unordered_map::contains
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains

Answer (score 13):

In C++20, you can use the `contains` method (added to all associative containers if I am not mistaken):

```
if (my_map.contains(k1) && my_map[k1].contains(k2))
{
    // do something with my_map[k1][k2]
}
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that the `k1` search is performed twice. A better solution would perform the `k2` search on the result of a single `k1` search.

Comment: Good point but they asked for the simplest way, not fastest. So I'm not sure if that would be a better solution for this question.

Answer (score 8):

You might also use `count` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/count/ )

which will return 0 if key not exist

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class M>
bool contains(M const&){return true;}
template<class M, class K, class...Ks>
bool contains(M const&m, K const&k, Ks const&...ks){
  auto it=m.find(k);
  if (it==m.end()) return false;
  return contains(it->second, ks...);
}
```

will work for every single-valued associative container.

`contains(my_map, k1, k2)` is true if there is an element `k1` which contains `k2`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (for the mutable case)

```
using inner_map = std::map<key_type, value_type>;
using outer_map = std::map<key_type, inner_map>

boost::optional<value_type&> 
element_for_keys(outer_map& map, const key_type& k1, const key_type& k2)
{
  auto it_outer = map.find(k1);
  if (it_outer = map.end())
    return {};
  auto &map2 = it_outer->second;
  auto it_inner = map2.find(k2);
  if (it_inner == map2.end())
    return {};

  return { it_inner->second };
}
```

called like so:

```
auto op_value = element_for_keys(my_map, kv1, kv2);
if (op_value) {
  // use op_value.value()
}
else {
  // handle case where it does not exist
}
```

... or there's the more python-like way...

```
try {
  auto& v = my_map.at(k1).at(k2);
  // use v
}
catch(const std::out_of_range & e) {
  // didn't find it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a multi-key syntax to check, but the simplest way would be to use the `find` method. You could write a simple function to apply it to a `unordered_map` of `unordered_map`s

[reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `std::pair` as key to transforming the two-level hashtable into one level hashtable, the benefit:

- Simpler code and structure
- Maybe faster than two-level hash table(We call fewer hash functions, get more compacted memory layout to be more cache-friendly)

The drawback: We have some key redundancy, so it would be a bad choice for large keys with many duplications, but this scenario won't be too common so the strategy here is still useful.

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int> map;
```

Then to check exists:

With find and compare with end iterator

```cpp
map.find(std::make_pair(k0, k1)) != map.end()
```

With the count function(Be aware that don't use it with unordered_multimap)

```cpp
map.count(std::make_pair(k0, k1)) != 0
```

or C++20 contains:

```cpp
map.contains(std::make_pair(k0, k1))
```