# Is casting to a bool a valid way to check for the existence of a unordered_map value matching a key? c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a nested unordered_map and would like to check whether a value has been created for a set of keys. Most of the solutions online like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512437/simplest-method-to-check-whether-unordered-map-of-unordered-maps-contains-key/34512483) suggest iterating through the keys to check for their existence. Is there an inherent problem with trying to access them and cast them to bool as I've done below? The output from the test leads me to believe it works.

```
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, const char*>> myMap;
    myMap[1][2]="abc";
    myMap[2][2]="false";
    std::cout <<(bool)myMap[1][2]<< std::endl;
    std::cout <<(bool)myMap[0][0]<< std::endl;
    std::cout <<(bool)myMap[0][0]<< std::endl;
    std::cout <<(bool)myMap[1][4]<< std::endl;
    std::cout <<(bool)myMap[2][2]<< std::endl;
```

Output

```
1
0
0
0
1
```

Comment: if your test works, then it works.

Comment: What this does is it creates the objects if they don't exist, and the default value for the created `std::unordered_map<int, const char*>` is empty, and the created `const char*` is `nullptr`. So it "works" but it changes the container, and it's indistinguishable from an actually null value

Comment: "Most of the solutions online like this suggest iterating through the keys to check for their existence." None of the solutions I saw there have any iteration. It's direct access. `map.find(k)` is O(1) (assuming a good hash function, of course)

Comment: I'd flag it in a code review for using C-style cast. All your code does is checking whether the pointer is null.

Comment: perhaps you could consider using `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, const char*>` instead. It would be simpler to use.

Comment: @Sopel unordered_map requires the creation of a custom hash function when using std::pair<int,int> as the key.

Comment: not simpler to create, simpler to use :)

Answer (score 2):

Invoking `operator[]` on a non-const `std::(unordered_)map` will create the requested element with a default value if it does not already exist, before then returning a reference to that element.  You are using that exact functionality when populating the `[1][2]` and `[2][2]` elements.

Your output contains 0's  because you are requesting keys that do not exist, so the `map`s are inserting those elements with default values, thus you end up with a null `char*` pointer that you are type-casting to `bool`.  Any non-null value is output as true/1, and any null value is output as false/0.

To simply check if an element exists, you can use the map's `find()` or `count()` method, or in C++20 the `contains()` method, eg:

```cpp
bool keysExist(
    const std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, const char*>> &m,
    int index1, int index2)
{
    auto iter = m.find(index1);
    return (iter != m.end()) && (iter->find(index2) != iter->end());
    // or: return (iter != m.end()) && (iter->count(index) == 1);
    // or: return (iter != m.end()) && iter->contains(index2);
}

std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, const char*>> myMap;
myMap[1][2] = "abc";
myMap[2][2] = "false";

std::cout << keysExist(myMap, 1, 2) << std::endl;
std::cout << keysExist(myMap, 0, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << keysExist(myMap, 0, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << keysExist(myMap, 1, 4) << std::endl;
std::cout << keysExist(myMap, 2, 2) << std::endl;
```

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to mention `count` and the (C++20) `contains`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: it doesn't have to be all-or-nothing, in your code `iter->find(index2) != iter->end())` can be simplified to `iter->contains(index2)`.